# How to get rid of ios beta update messages?

Tags: iphone, ios, beta

I keep getting these, awful, pop-ups - almost every time I open my phone from lock.

[image: blah]

> A new iOS update is now available. Please update from the iOS 11 beta.

I'm on 11.2 (15C5092b).

Software Update page says:

> iOS 11.2
>
> Your software is up to date.

So: What is this mess? and How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Do you have an iOS beta installed on this iPhone?

Comment: 11.2 is only beta atm, I believe.

Comment: I’ve been having this problem too, but I checked again just now and there is a software update. Perhaps there was some issue with deployment on Apple’s end ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’ve been getting this too. I fixed it by removing the iOS beta software profile by going to Settings → General → Profiles, select the Apple beta profile and hit remove. Restart your phone once removed.

Of course doing this removes the phone from receiving further beta updates, but retains the current iOS installed. You shouldn’t need minor iOS updates for development anyways.

Answer (score -5):

Apprentely this update is only for iPhone X (to allow it use beta version is)

Comment: I’ve got an iPhone 6....

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.